# Custom Taxonomy in Permalink from post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, rewrite-tag

I am using custom post types and custom taxonomies for that post type.
This snippet currently sets the permalinks for the post type:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'myrewritebase'),
```

I am registering the taxonmy this way:

```
register_taxonomy(
        'my_taxonomy',
        'my_post_type',
```

What do I have to set as rewrite for my custom post type?

I tried it this way:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => '%my_taxonomy%'),
```

This did not work.

Many Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Set your taxonomy slug to `taxonomy_name` and in your post type set the slug to `taxonomy_name/%taxonomy_name_term%` and flush rewrite rules (simply by going to permalink settings panel in the admin) And after that WordPress will be able to handle `/taxonomy_name/%taxonomy_name_term%/post-name/` URLs.

So all that is left to do is tell WordPress what `%taxonomy_name_term%` means and for that just add this function to your theme's functions.php file:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'events_permalink_structure', 10, 4);
function events_permalink_structure($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample)
{
    if ( false !== strpos( $post_link, '%taxonomy_name_term%' ) ) {
        $event_type_term = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'TAXONOMY_NAME' );
        $post_link = str_replace( '%taxonomy_name_term%', array_pop( $event_type_term )->slug, $post_link );
    }
    return $post_link;
}
```

Make sure you replace `TAXONOMY_NAME` with the actual name of the taxonomy.